# ReactJS No routes matched location because of question mark in query string

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a react app with this route, I use react-router-dom.

> <Route path='/contacts?page=:page' element={} />

And I navigate like that:

> navigate(`/contacts?page=${newPage}`);

but because of question mark, in the console appears "No routes matched location", when I change the question mark with other symbol for example _ everything is fine.

Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: what router library are you using ?

Comment: react-router-dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a couple of solutions for this

**Solution 1**

You could try with parameters like this

```
<Route path="/contacts/page/:page" component={} />
```

And navigate like this

```
navigate(/contacts/page/${newPage});
```

**Solution 2**

If you want to work with query strings, with question mark you dont have to mention it in your  simply add the query string (?page) and access it later like I did in this example

Example

```
<Route path='/contacts' element={} />
```

Navigate between pages the same way

```
navigate(/contacts?page=${newPage});
```

But you will have to access the page query string like this

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page</h1>
      <p>{new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('page')}</p>
    </div>
```

Hopefully this helps, but I'd recomend to go with the first solution

Comment: Is it right like that, shouldn't one query string be with question mark?

Comment: Check my edit, and hopefully that helps you!